# Unable to delegate Migrate SID History extended right

Tags: active-directory

I'm working on using ADMT 3.2 to migrate groups (including SIDs) and it works perfectly when I use domain admin credentials on both ends, but I'd really like to use a service account that is delegated something less than DA.  All the documentation I can find (such as [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776438(v=ws.10).aspx)) talks about delegating the Migrated SID History extended right, but when I use ADUC to delegate the rights that extended right is nowhere to be found.  I've tried looking for ways to unhide it and I've been unsuccessful.  What am I missing?  I'm doing the delegation as a domain admin.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I thought you could delegate this right at the OU level, but it has to be at the domain level.